# What is the difference (if any) between these two sentences?

Tags: usage, nuances

大学で勉強をしたいです。

大学で勉強したいです。

As far as I can tell both translate to - "I want to study at university". I'm just wondering if one sounds more 'natural' in Japanese than the other and indeed whether either structure is more approriate in different situations or not.

Comment: The latter sounds more natural to me.

Comment: @ちょこれーと But can you imagine a context which would make the former sound more natural?

Comment: @snailplane When you say what you want to study, then I think you need the を(orが). eg 大学で法学の勉強*を/が*したいです。(=大学で法学を勉強したいです。)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 大学で勉強をしたいです。

Here, `勉強{べんきょう}` is a noun, and `したい` is the verb being acted on it, so you have something like, "At university I want to *do* study." However, this direct English translation is a little ungrammatical, and the original Japanese isn't. So, with a little flexibility, perhaps we can capture the Japanese meaning with something like, "At university I really want to *do some study*!" By acting **on** the noun with a separate verb, it holds it up for emphasis.

> 大学で勉強したいです。

Here, `勉強{べんきょう}` is made into a verb by attaching `したい` directly to it without the `を` particle. It becomes, "At university I want to study." This would most likely be the preferred way of expressing the idea.

Depending on the context in which you were speaking, `勉強をしたい` could work, but if all you want to express is your desire to study at university, `大学で勉強したいです` is the more natural of the two.

Comment: I don't think an argument based on syntax really helps illuminate what the semantic difference is. `大学で勉強をしたい` doesn't sound unnatural because it sounds ungrammatical (like the English), but rather because the focus is weird for this specific sentence.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, Thanks for your comment, and I appreciate what you mean about focus, but there *is* a grammatical difference, and I think you might be discounting the unnaturalness of `勉強をしたい` too much.

Comment: I do not think `勉強をしたい` is inherently unnatural, I think it's just unnatural in this case due to the context. I guess we just disagree on that point, which is driving our different explanations.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, Fair enough. I agree it's not as unnatural as the English. Perhaps if you could think of an example where a `[noun]をする` construct merely created emphasis over the same noun in a `[noun]する` without sounding awkward, then that would drive your point home. As it is right now, I'm not sure what part of the context of `勉強` creates awkwardness that would not be there otherwise.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, I've updated my answer to reflect the concerns you raised. I hope it's improved.

Comment: If you want a translation in English which captures the nuance and has "do" in it, "In school, studying is what I want to do" is an option, but personally I think the "do" parallel is harmful rather than helpful here.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, could you elaborate on why "do" is a bad parallel for `する`? In my dictionary, "to do", is the first definition for `する`.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad parallel, I just think it's not a useful parallel to explain the difference between these two sentence's meanings. In other words, I don't think mirroring the Japanese syntax into the English syntax is particularly helpful for understanding the nuance in *meaning* here. Of course, if you feel it is helpful to yourself, then by all means; it's your answer.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, I feel I engaged you to address your legitimate concerns about factual accuracy, but I'm very sorry to say that the comment "helpful to yourself" comes across as a need to win an argument. Obviously, I put it as an answer because I feel it's helpful to others as well, and just because it's not the angle you would take doesn't mean it's not what others might benefit from. In the future, let's please just keep comments limited to trying to collaborate on the most accurate information possible, and leave it to individuals to decide what they find "useful" or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12501/discussion-between-darius-jahandarie-and-dave-m-g)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is mainly that when you include the を, it emphasizes 勉強 a little, which is odd for this sentence.

> 学校で勉強をしたいです
> "I want to *study* in school." (As opposed to doing something else in school.)
>
> 学校で勉強したいです
> "I want to study in school."

With the right context, perhaps the former could be more natural, like if someone was annoying you to play a game or something, you could response 「学校で勉強をしたいですけど」 and it would be perfectly natural.

All that said, this nuance is very faint, I do not think anyone would look at you weird if you said the first thing even if you didn't want that extra implication.